# Where is the Log.d file stored on the Android phone

Tags: file, logging

Where is the Log.d file stored on the Android phone? Or is it stored on the phone?  I want to use it to inspect the results of try/catch when the app crashes.  The app doesn't crash in the debugger or on an Android 4.1 phone, but it crashes on a Froyo phone.  I'm trying to trace which line(s) the crash is coming from.

Update:
I learned how to debug directly on the phone with USB debugging.  It is easier than I thought, and faster than the emulator.  It would still be nice to know where the Log.d file is kept though.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace your lines by `Log.d` in `logcat` in `debug` section.

Generally use the Log.v() Log.d() Log.i() Log.w() and Log.e() methods.(section -**VERBOSE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN,ERROR respectively**)

```
The order in terms of verbosity, from least to most is 
ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE.
Verbose should never be compiled into an application except during development.
Debug logs are compiled in but stripped at runtime. Error, warning and info 
logs are always kept.
```

Comment: Are these files stored on the phone, or displayed only at runtime?

Comment: No it does not store in phone. Yes it displays at runtime.